# Check whether a control is available in td

Tags: javascript

Inside table td i have control(s).  there must be one control inside td but can be multiple. I can get first control the following way.

```
ctrlTable.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("*")[0].value;
```

So how to check whether the "td"/cell[1] has more control

Thanks,

Comment: What is a "control"? `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList which has a `length` attribute.

Comment: It's dynamic table. It can be any control. that's why i put getElementsByTagName(*). * can be any control. Now i need to check getElementsByTagName(*)[1] is available or not

Comment: What do you consider to be a control? text input/select only? do buttons count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way;

```
function countEls(cell) {
    var lookFor = ["INPUT", "SELECT", "BUTTON"];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lookFor.length; i++) {
        count += cell.getElementsByTagName(lookFor[i]).length;
    }
    return count;
}

alert(countEls(ctrlTable.rows[i].cells[1]))​;
```

Answer (score 1):

To check the number of children on any DOM element, you can use the `childNodes[]` property, e.g.:

```
ctrlTable.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes.length > 0
```

Comment: Worth noting this will be 1 if there is any whitespace in the <td> </td>